# Variable global da undefined no cambia via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando obtener un dato via ajax y ese dato quiero asignarselo a una variable global, pero esa variable global da undefined

```
 var x;
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
      ayuda();
      break;
  }
});
function ayuda(){
   nivel_id();
//AQUI ME MUESTRA undefined===x
  console.log(x+"===x");
 }

//async && await
function  nivel_id() {
  var STEP = 0;
  $.ajax({
    data: STEP,
url: "scripts/datagame3.php",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        x = data;
//AQUI ME MUESTRA 1==Data, que esto es correcto
        console.log(data+"==Data");
    },
  });
}
```

Eh intetado con haciendo asincrona la funcion ayuda() y ponerle el await cuando llame la funcion nivel_id() pero siempre primero me imprime en esta orden ponga o no ponga el await
undefined===x
1==Data
Como que tarda en obtener el  dato ajax por por que despues de eso vuelvo a presionar la flecha IZ y ya me da el dato así:
1===x
1==Data

Answer (score 0):

Te esta ocurriendo esto ya que ajax es asíncrono es decir realiza la llamada y no espera a que retorne el resultado continua con la ejecución del programa hace el console log de

```
function ayuda(){
   nivel_id();
//AQUI ME MUESTRA undefined===x
  console.log(x+"===x"); //este console log
 }
```

y luego espera la llamada de ajax y te imprime el valor en el return de la llamada ajax

```
function  nivel_id() {
  var STEP = 0;
  $.ajax({
    data: STEP,
url: "scripts/datagame3.php",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        x = data;
//AQUI ME MUESTRA 1==Data, que esto es correcto
        console.log(data+"==Data"); //este 
    },
  });
}
```

como en la función anterior has realizado `x=data` ahora x ya vale 1 por lo que al volver a ejecutar `ayuda()` va a hacer exactamente lo mismo va  a hacer la llamada ajax y continuar la ejecución pero en este caso el  `console.log(x+"===x");` ya tiene valor de la ejecución anterior te imprime el valor y luego imprime el de la llamada ajax

Para solucionarlo si quieres que siempre te imprima  el valor de la llamada tendrás que hacerlo síncrono es decir tienes que ponerle en la propiedad de ajax esto

Te dejo dos links uno en el que explican [la diferencia de síncrono y asíncrono](https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/jquery/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-async-false-y-async-true-en-jquery-ajax/1042877669/) y [la documentacion de de jquery sobre ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)